# How to get Controller name, and data available in a base Controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, controller

**I have 2 questions.**

First, background:

I have a `PageController : Controller` and `SearchController : PageController`

PageController is defined as:

```
public class PageController : Controller
{
    protected ISite Site;
    protected PageConfiguration PageConfiguration;

    protected override void Initialize(RequestContext rc)
    {
        this.Site = new Site(SessionUser.Instance().SiteId);

        this.PageConfiguration = this.Site.CurrentSite.GetPage(/* controller name */);

        base.Initialize(rc);
    }
}
```

I have Site & PageConfiguration stored in PageController because every page that implements PageController needs them

**Question 1:**
I'm trying to port this from an existing ASP.NET app. that requires a page name to get the PageConfiguration object. Instead of a page name, I'm going to use the Controller's name instead. What's the best way for me to get that as a string?

**Question 2:**
I'm trying to render a PartialView which relies on that data, as follows:

```
<%@ Page Title="" 
    Language="C#" 
    MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" 
    Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<PageConfiguration>" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="tstFactsheetGenerator.Models.Panels"%>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

    <% Html.RenderPartial("Search", new Search { PanelConfiguration = Model.Panels[0] }); %>
</asp:Content>
```

I can see that when the RenderPartial() method is called the PageConfiguration Model has has the Panel I need. But in the constructor for the Search class that PanelConfiguration is null.

Is there a better & more effective way to make the data I need for the page available? Thanks.

Comment: Can you show how you set Panel?

Comment: Panel is set when the PageConfiguration object is created.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Question 1:

```
protected override void Initialize(RequestContext rc)
{
    ...
    var controllerName = requestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"]
    ...
}
```

Question 2:

As you are using class initializer syntax (`new { PanelConfiguration = ... }`) the `PanelConfiguration` will be null in the constructor of the `Search` class but does it matter? You shouldn't be using the `PanelConfiguration` property there. In the `Search` partial it will be initialized. If you need to use it in the constructor (I don't see why you would need it) you could add it as constructor argument.

Comment: Thanks Darin. The reason I need an instance of a Search object is becase PanelConfiguration is a bit meaningless on its own in a PartialView. I need to use the info in PanelConfiguration to get the data Search needs to populate the Partial with. Can you tell me if there's a better way to go about this?